# Pyqt5 Progress Bar

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
def retranslateUi(self,Mainwindow):
    #this is the main window UI
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start")) # this is my start Button to run long script
def long_script_run():
    """
    my function that could run 1 min script
    """
    self.progressBar.setValue(val) # this will set the value to 100% in my progressbar
```

What is the best approach to run the progressbar from starting 1 value from my long script until it finish and set the value of 100%? I tried the Qthread but the problem they are not ending in same time.

Please help thank you

Comment: You need to use signals and slots api.  Please create [example]

Comment: Can you give details about `long_script_run()`? Is it calling an external function or is it a "local" python function?  In the second case you certainly can split the function into smaller pieces and regularly update your progress.

Comment: It is internal function and  inside of my function are automating a browser using  selenium

Comment: Do you have ways to track the progress of that function? If not, you cannot show a valid progress value: if you don't know how many miles you have to drive, consequentially you cannot know the *progress* of that route until you're arrived.

Comment: I am planning to make a for loop and use a multiprocessing and do the timing of the end of the loop but still not good way I guess